# didSelectRowAtIndexPath: how to get old indexPath to deselect checkmark?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

How to deselect previously selected row in tableView ?? I can't find solution to obtain oldIndexPath

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (newCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you store the previous index path, you won't be able to retrieve it.
Just store it in an ivar, when you detect a row is selected, the next time you will be able to remove the checkmark on the previous cell.